# TFS Backlog Missing

Tags: tfs

In all of the documentation on msdn, I see a a "Backlog items" list on the TFS Work page.  For example:

[image]

However, I don't see that in my project.  Mine shows only Features and User Stories:

[image]

This is a project I inherited.  It's hosted on-premise.  I believe the process template is a customized version of the agile process template.  How can I get the "backlog items" list back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Agile template uses User Stories. The Scrum template uses Product Backlog Items. They serve the same purpose; it's mostly a terminology thing. You can't really switch between different process templates.

Comment: But agile still has a backlog.  So the "stories" list is the backlog?

Comment: If you  don't have a lot of data, or  don'tcare  about history then it is easy to  switch from the Agile template to the Scrum template: http://nkdagility.com/upgrading-your-process-template-from-msf-for-agile-4-to-visual-studio-scrum-2-x/